# Many to many relationship with cascade or set null delete?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

`Languages` and `Occasions`

Between these tables there is third related table:

```
Occasions_has_languages
```

with the following stucture:

```
id | languege_id | occasion_id
1    1             1
```

In case when I delete language with `id = 1` it has sense to store NULL in

```
Occasions_has_languages.languege_id
```

The same with deleting `occasion` I can set NULL to

```
Occasions_has_languages.occasion_id
```

When `Occasions_has_languages.languege_id` and `Occasions_has_languages.occasion_id` are NULL, it should be deleted forever.

Am I right about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a case of N:N relation intermediate table (`Occasions_has_languages` in your case) is used only for relation definition and hence `null` values in it have no sense because they don't define the relationship between tables.

The correct way, in this case, is to use `on delete cascade` for references from `Occasions_has_languages` to `Languages` and `Occasions` so incomplete references will be deleted automatically.

Comment: Do you mean to use CASCADE property for `Occasions_has_languages.languege_id` and `Occasions_has_languages.occasion_id`?

Comment: Yes, because your description tells that elements from both tables can be deleted. Default behavior of [referential action](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) in MySQL is `RESTRICT` so you will not be able to delete rows from a table that have no referential action

Comment: I am agree only with `Occasions_has_languages.occasion_id`. It should be CASCADE. But why I can not set NULL for `Occasions_has_languages.languege_id`, after I can assign value is not?

Comment: You can, of course use `SET NULL`, but it will mean that at some point of time your intermediate table will have references that leads to nowhere. If it is acceptable for you - it is ok, but usually removal an N:N reference means deletion of reference row from intermediate table. It also simplifies references construction because you don't need to search for potentially spare reference, but just create one.

Comment: Thank you, what about UPDATE, is it the similar?

Comment: It will depend on application's logic (e.g. will you allow multiple copies of same reference or not, in last case you may also want to construct unique key from both foreign ids), but generally speaking you can simply update foreign ids into intermediate table to update N:N reference.